# Powershell Open text file print it on exit

Tags: powershell, printing, start-process

I have a text file that I need to open in Notepad.exe and have the user add some input to it. Then I would like to print the file to AdobePDF when the user exits the file.

Here is what I have to open the file

```
Start-Process notepad.exe C:\path\to\text\file\MyTextFile.txt -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

Not sure how to Print PDF on exit. AdobePDF is an installed printer but it is NOT THE DEFAULT printer. Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this,

```
$TxtFilePath = "C:\folder\txtfile.txt"
Start-Process notepad.exe $TxtFilePath -NoNewWindow -Wait #Assuming user save the file
Get-Content -Path $TxtFilePath| Out-Printer PDFCreator #PDFCreator is the printer name for PDF
```

**--EDIT--**

I could not figure out a direct approach to retain the file name, kind of wrote a hack with ms word,

```
Function Save-TxtAsPDF
{
    Param([string] $FilePath, [string] $OutFolder)

    # Required Word Variables
    $ExportASPDFConstant = 17
    $DoNotSaveConstant = 0

    # Create a hidden Word window
    $word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
    $word.visible = $false

    # Add a Word document
    $doc = $word.documents.add()

    # Put the text into the Word document
    $txt = Get-Content $FilePath
    $selection = $word.selection
    $selection.typeText($txt)

    # Set the page orientation to landscape
    $doc.PageSetup.Orientation = 1

    $FileName = (Split-Path -Path $FilePath -Leaf).Replace(".txt",".pdf")  


    $DestinationPath = Join-Path $OutFolder $FileName

    # Export the PDF file and close without saving a Word document
    $doc.ExportAsFixedFormat($DestinationPath,$ExportASPDFConstant)
    $doc.close([ref]$DoNotSaveConstant)
    $word.Quit()
}


$TxtFilePath = "C:\folder\tt.txt"
$OutFolder = "C:\Outputfolder"

Start-Process notepad.exe $TxtFilePath -NoNewWindow -Wait #Assuming user save the file

Save-TxtAsPDF -FilePath $TxtFilePath -OutFolder $OutFolder
```

See if that helps!

Comment: This worked great. However I wonder if there is a way to keep the original text file name when saving the pdf?

Comment: Updated the answer, could not find a direct approach! See if that helps!